# ~RVM_PROJECT_PATH in oh-my-zsh prompt

Tags: rvm, oh-my-zsh

Recently installed .oh-my-zsh on a new machine on which RVM was already installed.

Noticed that in several of my Rails project directories, I now see this instead of the actual name of the project directory:

```
➜  ~RVM_PROJECT_PATH git:(master)
```

All other behavior seems normal, but I'm finding it difficult to pin down the cause in the .oh-my-zsh configuration.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

it is a bug in your Zsh, to avoid it use `%1/` in `PROMPT` instead of `%.` or `%C` or `%1~`

more info: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3091

this bug should be fixed in `zsh 5.0.7` ... or with this https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/3252

Comment: In this particular case, I was using the robbyrussell.zsh-theme, and based on the thread you referenced, the fix was to change %c to %1/.

Comment: As per update to the issue 3091 in zsh. This is actually a bug in oh-my-zsh... and not in zsh.

Comment: Tim what about the part that variables longer then their value are displayed?

Answer (score 10):

oh-my-zsh has been updated to fix this issue. Forcing an upgrade of oh-my-zsh fixed the problem for me.

```
$ source ~/.oh-my-zsh/tools/upgrade.sh
```

Comment: Upgrading oh-my-zsh doesn't improve the situation for me. any clues?

Answer (score 3):

So, I was really struggling with this for a while. I'm not using oh-my-zsh, just straight zsh, but had the same issues. Upgraded a lot of stuff. After digging through this huge script and trying lots of suggestions, this finally worked for me:

`hash -rd`

I just put this before I set my variable holding the directory. My config now looks like this:

`30   hash -rd
 31   local promptsize=${#${():---(${PR_GEMSET}${PR_BRANCH})---()--}} 
 32   local pwdsize=${#${(%):-%~}}`

Note that the issue was with the `%~`. Just thought I'd share what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for zsh 5.0.2 in Ubuntu 14.04. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this on console, my problem is solved.

PROMPT='%F{green}%1/ ${vcs_info_msg_0_}$ '