# ~RVM_PROJECT_PATH in oh-my-zsh prompt with updated oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I have the same problem as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369548/rvm-project-path-in-oh-my-zsh-prompt) on stackoverflow, the solutions provided there don't work for me, as `%1/` only prints the last directory name, and I would like to have the behavior of `%~` instead.

It was mentioned to update zsh with `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` command, but after running it I get no improvements.

What else could I try?

here's my theme (based on the candy one):

```
 PROMPT=$'[%{$fg_bold[green]%}%n@%m:%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[white]%}%~%{$reset_color%}] %{$fg[blue]%}[%*] $(git_prompt_info)\
%{$fg_bold[blue]%}%#%{$reset_color%} '

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[green]%}["
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="]%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY=" %{$fg[red]%}*%{$fg[green]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN=""
```

thanks,

Comment: Have you tried `unsetopt autonamedirs`?

Comment: mmh, never heard of that, how do I try that?

Comment: Add this to end of your zshrc, for instance.

Comment: Or you can type that into your shell to see the effect immediately.

Comment: Thanks, that did improve the situation, now in the prompt I see alternatively: `~/Documents/rails/NAMEDDIR` and `~NAMEDDIR`.. not completely perfect, but at least I get the prompt to show the pwd info.